# SQL запрос: умножить каждое значение

Tags: sql

Доброе время суток, скажите вот этот код:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_birja SET ammount = ammount - '" + textAmmount.Text + "' WHERE user_id = '" + user_id + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Он отнимает от ammount то, что лежит в TextBox'e, так вот, а скажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы каждое значение textAmmount'a было ещё умножено, например, на 2 или любое число. Вот покажу, как примерно, выглядит формула

```
ammount = ammount - (25 * 2)
```

Вот только, как это изобразить в SQL запросе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, и в чем тут проблема?

```
UPDATE t_birja SET ammount = (ammount - ('" + textAmmount.Text + "' * 2)) WHERE user_id = '" + user_id + "'";
```